# Unable to remove learndash columns using learndash-assignment-list-columns hook

Tags: php, wordpress, learndash

Hi I am trying to remove date and comments from assignment listing from learndash plugin currently I have tried below code but it was not working. Any other suggestions will be very grateful

```
apply_filters( 'learndash-assignment-list-columns',
function( $columns ) {
  // Unset columns
  unset($columns['date']);
  unset($columns['comments']);

  // Always return $columns.
  return $columns;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply_filters` is wrong in your code. `apply_filters` is used to provide filters for something. you need to use `add_filter` since you have to add your function in `learndash-assignment-list-columns` filter.

So your code should be:

```php
add_filter(
    'learndash-assignment-list-columns',
    function( $columns ) {
        // Unset columns.
        unset( $columns['date'] );
        unset( $columns['comments'] );

        // Always return $columns.
        return $columns;
    }
);
```

Learndash already have examples for this filter https://developers.learndash.com/hook/learndash-assignment-list-columns/#examples